# Kodi add-on - Small title in player

Tags: python, add-on, xbmc, kodi

How can I get put these information to Video file when playing on Kodi Player.
shown in picture below 'Beck - Mutations'

I have searched every where and find nothing.

[image]

normal code is like this.

```
    li = xbmcgui.ListItem('Title', thumbnailImage='http://exaple.com/image.png')
    contextMenu = []
    li.addContextMenuItems(contextMenu, replaceItems = True)
    li.setInfo( "video", { "Title" : 'Title when Play', "AlbumArtist " : 'Some artist' } )
    xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItem(handle=int(sys.argv[1]), url='http://example.com/sample.m3u8', listitem=li)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I was searching through Youtube before and it's difficult to find. 
finally I got it.

```
    li = xbmcgui.ListItem('title', thumbnailImage='http://image.com/image.png')
    li.setInfo( "audio", { "Title" : 'hellop', "Artist" : ['Some artist'], "Studio" : 'canal' } )
    xbmcplugin.addDirectoryItem(handle=int(sys.argv[1]), url="http://example.com/sample.m3u8" listitem=li)
```

I have wrongly added space in Artist title. Removed and rename it as Artist. Artist should be list of artists. after that it will show up.